# How to make closing credits page - animate TableLayout without being cut at display dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-tablelayout, credits

EDIT:
solved! Awnser 1. can't push/vote it up

I'm trying to figure out for hours what's the best way to make an "closing credits" activity. Right now I have a `TableLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` to center the table.
I am using a simple animation file:

```
<translate
android:duration="20000" 
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

The problem is, the credits table is much bigger than the screen, around 4 times bigger 
so the table gets cut at screen dimension. Animation works fine, but only the viewable part of the table walks through the display.

Is there a smarter way to create closing credits? Is it possible in android to not cut the table at display dimensions?

Maybe this is too much text anyway? (with `ScrollView` I get "View too large to fit into drawing cache")

EDIT:
With Luksprog help I got the whole table to scrolldown. Like already mentioned, it's much to fast now. Now I have problems to control the speed via an handler or timertask. because to display and make the table scrollable, i found in the web this solution, otherwise it didn't scroll:

```
public class Credits extends Activity {
int mesuredHeightScroll;
ScrollView scroll;
boolean first_time = true;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (first_time == true) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.credits);
        scrolldownthetable();
    }
}

private void scrolldownthetable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrolltable);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            scroll.smoothScrollTo(0, mesuredHeightTable);

        }
    };
    table.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
};

/**
 * Draw the Layout, otherwise getMesuredHeight returns 0, null onCreate 
 * to call it again, first time to false, so onCreate doesn't call again on
 * focus change (resume,pause...)
 */
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrolltable);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    mesuredHeightTable = table.getMeasuredHeight();
    mesuredHeightScroll = scroll.getMeasuredHeight();

    onCreate(null);
    first_time = false;
}
```

}

Is there anyway to get this scrollTo() automated inside the Globallayoutlistener?
Or is my code stupid and theres a more comfortable way?
It would be great if someone could help me with some code, because i am running out of time :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a smarter way to create closing credits? Is it possible
>   android not to cut the table at displydimensions?

As your table is most likely enclosed in a `ScrollView` you could add another view at the bottom that is as big as the screen and then use the [`smoothScrollTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29) on the `ScrollView` itself.

As you probably want more control over the animation, especially the speed, I think you could use a `Handler` or `CountDownTimer` to simply call `scrollTo()` on the `ScrollView` at short time intervals.

Comment: when i set scroll.smoothScrollTo(int,int); what should be the x and y ints like? when i add a view at the bottom as big as the screen, would that be enough, cause my table is like 4 times larger than screensize. thx

Comment: @eyjin `x` would be 0 and `y` would be the sum of all the views heights(`view.getMeasuredHeight()`) from the `ScrollView` without the last added empty view.

Comment: hey Luksprog, maybe you could help me with the new code i posted? Thank you so far

Comment: @eyjin I've made a little sample about this. You can find it here https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/view/RollingCredits.java . It's self explanatory but ask if you have problems.

Comment: wow thanks a lot, you blew me away :D it works fine! I hope others will benefit too from your work!

Comment: @eyjin No problem. If my answer helped you could mark it as correct with the check mark near the answer.